# webkit based browser interpretate the json as a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, webkit, jsonp

im just tryin to get my zootool items via js to push them in my blog's footer...but with no success.
here's the code im using
(jquery framework)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{

//first try
var url = "http://zootool.com/api/users/items/?username=USER_NAME&apikey=API_KEY&jsonpcallback=?"
$.getJSON(url, function(data){ console.log(data); });

//second try
url2 = "http://zootool.com/api/users/items/?";
data = "username=USER_NAME&apikey=API_KEY";

$.ajax(
{
 url: url2, dataType: 'jsonp', data: data,
 success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
});

}
```

webkit based browser tells me that:
"Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json."

firefox works good, i get an application/json; utf-8 object that i can parse succesfully.
do you know what could be the problem?
thanks a lot in advance!

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directly from the creator of zootool:

---

the api hasn't supported callbacks for jsonp so far. I just added them so your first version should work with a little adjustment. you have to rename jsonpcallback to callback to make it work. take a look here:

http://pastebin.com/vA9wcySa

Answer (score 5):

A JSONP response is not really JSON but JavaScript, so the Content-Type in the response header should be application/javascript.

Comment: This solves the issue in webkit and doesn't break anything in other browsers, thanks. However, I would recommend using `text/javascript` because of compatibility issues:  http://www.hafnerdesigns.com/blog/2009/03/difference-between-textjavascript-applicationjavascript/