# JQuery interpreting json as script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If you all could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

This is the error I am getting:

> "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json." ("Resource" is referring to is the json response from google's servers.)

Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false&callback=?", function(jsondata) {
    });
  });
```

Comment: when i run that code i get "please use a post request" as the json response...  perhaps try the $.ajax instead, specifying post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var loc = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': loc },
            function(data, status) { console.log(data); });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are possibly the most awesome person ever. Thank you so much!

Comment: Agreed, I've been looking for this exact solution. You are THE BOSS.

Comment: Out of curiosity... does anyone understand how google's apis for geocoding work (which one to use when), it seems like there are a couple different options, each of them working differently and with different restrictions and capabilities. Very confusing to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

The site you are calling does not support JSONP, only returns as JSON.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the response, but do you know how I could make my code work, now that I know the site I am calling only responds in json?

Comment: @Andrew - my answer to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281039/jquery-wont-get-json/5281137#5281137) showed how you could use the api objects to use geocoding. I can repost it here if you want...

Comment: Be aware that use of the geocoding only allows you to use the data in accordance with a Google Map. Take a look at the Terms Of Use

Answer (score 1):

In order to get JSON from another domain (such as googleapis.com), you **must** use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) rather than plain JSON (for more info, read up on [same origin policy](http://www.google.com/search?q=same+origin+policy)).

Fortunately, adding a GET parameter whose value is a question mark (`callback=?`, in your code) causes jQuery to attempt to make a JSONP call.  *Un*fortunately, the site is ignoring your request for JSONP and serving straight JSON.

The two possible causes are that the site doesn't support JSONP (which would be odd for a public Google API) or that it expects the name to be something else (i.e. not `callback=`).  Check out the Google API docs to see what the they expect / support.

Comment: supported options: callback, base_domain, language, other_params --- apparently google does accept callback; thanks for eliminating one possible source of error, though

Answer (score 0):

So my Maps API is a bit rusty, but doesn't the `callback=?` at the end turn the output into a [JSONP result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), which is indeed a script?

Try ditching the callback part of the query string.

Comment: If I do that, then I end up with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. :(     That is actually what I just fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if this answers your question: [webkit based browser interpretate the json as a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364366/jquery-jsonp-webkit-based-browser-interpretate-the-json-as-a-script)